# Raise event of class member object while overriding sender

Tags: c#, events, sender, class-members

I have a `MyEvent` event defined in `Class B` and a delegate for a handler of the event as `MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e)`.

My application has several instances of `Class A`, and each `Class A` has a single member instance of `Class B`.

If `Class A` subscribes a handler to `ClassB.MyEvent` then `sender` will be the instance of `Class B` that raised the event and `e` will be the `MyEventArgs` from the `Class B` call to `OnMyEvent(e)`.

However - what I really want is for the Application to subscribe a handler to `ClassA.ClassB.MyEvent` (or `ClassA.ClassBMyEvent` as appropriate) with `sender` representing the instance of `Class A` that *has* the instance of `Class B` that raised the event, and with `e` still being the `MyEventArgs` from the `Class B` call to `OnMyEvent(e)`.

I can create a sort of `WrapperEvent` in `Class A` which is raised by a handler in `Class A` which subscribes to `ClassB.MyEvent`, but this seems inelegant and I wondered if there is a cleaner way to do this?

---

Code snippets per request:

```
public class ClassB
{
    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

    public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public MyEventArgs()
        { }
    }

    private virtual void OnMyEvent(MyEventArgs e)
    {
        MyEventHandler handler = MyEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public ClassB()
    {
        /// do stuff
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        OnMyEvent(new MyEventArgs());
    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    private ClassB member = new ClassB();

    public ClassA()
    {
        /// do stuff
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        member.Method();
    }

}

static class Program
{
    static List<ClassA> aList = new List<ClassA>();

    static void Main()
    {
        aList.Add(new ClassA());

        /// I would like to be able to do this...

        aList[0].MyEvent += MyEvent_handler;

        aList[0].Method();
    }

    void MyEvent_handler(object sender, ClassB.MyEventArgs e)
    {
        /// ... such that sender is the ClassA instance i.e. aList[0]
        /// and e is the MyEventArgs passed to OnMyEvent in ClassB
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the best I could with the title of this question but please feel free to edit it... my head is spinning :-)

Comment: One suggestion - You need not define delegate EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) for your event. It is provided by default. `public event EventHandler EventName;` is enough.

Comment: Thanks @dotnetkid. Actually I was only using this an example; I am using a custom MyEventArgs class extending EventArgs and I think I had better edit the question as such to avoid distraction.

Comment: I also think it would be better if you cut the description length and provide actual class definitions instead. That will help more to readers. It is understandable currently too, however just like they say "Picture is worth a thousand words", I feel, same goes for the code snippets.

Comment: I personally think the description is easier to digest in this case ;-)